# Crash in MediaToolbox __setVideoBounds_block_invoke tvOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, tvos

getting crash while playing video uusing AVPlayer

working for all the tvOS versions only crashing for tvOS 14

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x54a8 objc_msgSend + 8
1  MediaToolbox                   0x2ba198 __setVideoBounds_block_invoke + 84
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x579c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x6fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x13de4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 872
5  CoreFoundation                 0x9d030 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6  CoreFoundation                 0x974e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480
7  CoreFoundation                 0x96600 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
8  GraphicsServices               0x6598 GSEventRunModal + 160
9  UIKitCore                      0x9e3b98 -[UIApplication _run] + 1060
10 UIKitCore                      0x9e9148 UIApplicationMain + 164
11 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0xf7a4 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 100
12 hotstarx-tvos                  0x7350 main + 4313412432 (RequestButton.swift:4313412432)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x25fc start + 4
```